# Agregar salto de linea despues de n elemento

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed

he estado limpiando un txt utilizando awk y sed para que sea mejor leíble, hasta el momento he ido bien pero me falta el ultimo paso la primera imagen muestra como lo tengo la segunda como lo necesito.

```
fech=`date "+%Y%m%d"`

#SACAR LOS DATOS DE BOLETA
awk -F ":" '/^5/{print $2}; /Total Mes/{print $2};/Monto Anterior/{print $2}; /Total a Pagar/{print $2}' boleta.lis > datosBol.txt

#ELIMINA TAB Y ESPACIOS EN BLANCOS
sed 's/ //g' datosBol.txt > limpioBol.txt

#PASAR DE FILAS A COLUMNAS
for ((i=1;i<=1;i++)); do cut -d: -f "$i" limpioBol.txt | paste -sd: ; done | column -t -s: > believeBoleta-$fech.txt
```

[image: Como lo tengo]

[image: Como Quiero que quede]

espero que me ayuden saludos.

Comment: Bienvenid(e?) a SO! Podrías agregar el comando que estás usando para hacer la generación actualmente? Y por favor, no coloques imágenes en las perguntas. Sería mejor que coloques el texto (hay cuestiones de formateo disponibles para que aparezca de forma adecuada).

Comment: fech=`date "+%Y%m%d"`

#SACAR LOS DATOS DE BOLETA
awk -F ":" '/^5/{print $2}; /Total Mes/{print $2};/Monto Anterior/{print $2}; /Total a Pagar/{print $2}' boleta.lis > datosBol.txt

#ELIMINA TAB Y ESPACIOS EN BLANCOS
sed 's/ //g' datosBol.txt > limpioBol.txt

#PASAR DE FILAS A COLUMNAS
for ((i=1;i<=1;i++)); do cut -d: -f "$i" limpioBol.txt | paste -sd: ; done | column -t -s: > believeBoleta-$fech.txt

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/484555/como-realizar-un-salto-de-linea-cada-x-cantidad-de-registro-con-awk-o-sed  ?