# como realizar un salto de linea cada x cantidad de registro con awk o sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

tengo un problema no se como agregar un salto de linea cada x cantidad de registro,
ejemplo.

tengo esto

```
1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888
```

necesito esto

```
1111 2222 3333 4444 
5555 6666 7777 8888
```

ayudenme no tengo mucho conocimiento en sed o awk.

Comment: ¿Es necesario hacerlo con awk?, segun lo que tienes y lo que quieres, se puede ver que lo unico que necesitas es romper tu linea en **dos** e imprimir cada mitad de linea en una nueva linea, ¿es eso lo que quieres ?

Comment: `awk -v x="4" '{for (idx = 1; idx <= NF; idx++) { printf("%s", $idx); if (idx < NF && idx % x != 0) {printf(OFS)} else {printf("\n")} }}'`

Comment: @ArnaudValmary o incluso `{ printf("%s%s", $idx, (idx < NF && idx % x != 0) ? OFS : RS) }}` o `{ printf("%s%s", $idx, (idx < NF && idx % x) ? OFS : RS) }}`.